# Groovy - Regular expression doesn't behave the way it should

Tags: regex, groovy

I want to extract a number from a line in a HTML file. I read the file line by line and want to get the number from the line in question by using regular expressions.

I've tried it like this:

```
def reportFileContents = new File("-path to file-").text
                reportFileContents.eachLine{ line -> 

                    def valueMatcher = /[n50 length] [*]([0-9]+)/
                    def matcher = (line =~ valueMatcher)

                }
```

But when I print out my 'matcher' I just get something like this:

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[n50 length] [*]([0-9]+) region=0,22 lastmatch=]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand what you think you're trying to do with that regexp, particularly the first character class block.  In any case, the type of "java.util.regex.Matcher" is correct.  Just look at examples like http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#groovy-operators .

Comment: Your regex doesn't make sense. As @DavidM.Karr points out, your output is exactly what it should be, so you aren't doing anything wrong in that case. If you want help with your regex you need to include what you're trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saying you are trying to match a string like `[n50 length] [*]123`?  If so, see my example below.

```
def textWithMatches = '''blah blah blah [n50 length] [*]123 blah blah blah
                        |nothing here
                        |something else [n50 length] [*]321 something else'''.stripMargin()

def textWithNoMatches = 'no matches here'

assert (textWithMatches =~ /\[n50 length\] \[\*\](\d+)/).collect { it[1] } == [123, 321]
assert (textWithNoMatches =~ /\[n50 length\] \[\*\](\d+)/).collect { it[1] } == []
```